# VS Code Highlight syntax

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm using the Hightlight Extension in VS Code that would markup parts of the code.
I have sql models and what I want to do is to highlight when I have a combination at the join level. Eg:

```
Join table2 T1 ON t1.dbid = t2.dbid
```

so the pattern would be * **join** + word + **ON** + word.**dbid** = word.**dbid**

I've tried various combinations but nothing worked perfectly. Even tried a Regex generator.

```
(?i)^join [a-zA-Z]+ on +[a-zA-Z]+._db_id = [a-zA-Z]+._db_id$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your expression doesn't account for table alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
join\s+.*?\s+on\s+[^.]*?\.dbid\s*=\s*[^.]*?\.dbid
```

Important point: be sure you are not set as "Match case".

↓ tested here ↓

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ucwn4f/1)